# What is wrong in my deployment ? Full text search with sunspot_rails gem on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sunspot-rails

I have a simple blog application with full text search using sunspot_rails gem. The application works well in development mode. So, I proceeded to deployment on heroku. However, something appears to be wrong in production and I cannot figure it out.

When I run :

```
heroku run rake console
```

I get the following log:

```
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.8600
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `user_configuration'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:281:in `user_configuration_from_key'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:256:in `disabled?'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails.rb:30:in `build_session'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/init.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot_rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:60:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579536+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579573+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579609+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579629+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579667+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579686+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579738+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579757+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579776+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579795+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-08-25T22:43:44.646789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T22:43:44.676708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-25T23:20:41.563452+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach WEBSOLR resource by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:20:41.563568+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:20:41.936820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-25T23:20:55.449181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 22273 -e production`
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247768+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:281:in `user_configuration_from_key'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247772+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/init.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247780+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247739+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247781+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot_rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247765+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `user_configuration'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247769+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:256:in `disabled?'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247771+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails.rb:30:in `build_session'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247784+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247787+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247785+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247790+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247791+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247793+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247797+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247808+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247775+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247776+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2015-08-25T23:21:03.229459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-25T23:21:03.229459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-25T23:21:03.216723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:21:09.602918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 13571 -e production`
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306158+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `user_configuration'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306178+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306194+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306137+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306176+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot_rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306193+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306164+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:281:in `user_configuration_from_key'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306195+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306166+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:256:in `disabled?'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306197+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306168+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails.rb:30:in `build_session'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306182+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306198+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306169+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/init.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306172+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306173+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306190+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306175+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306191+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:15.207054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:21:16.134189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=moussa-simple-rails-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=dc366c4d-46ea-4ff9-aca3-23300655b667 fwd="158.222.193.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-25T23:21:16.358726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=moussa-simple-rails-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=de0db63a-645b-4c26-a3af-58f41b6aa66b fwd="158.222.193.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-25T23:21:15.227907+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-25T23:21:46.699099+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:21:52.671551+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: Awaiting client
2015-08-25T23:21:52.699360+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-08-25T23:21:52.915042+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-25T23:21:57.420588+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-25T23:21:57.408745+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:32:04.600004+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake console` by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:32:13.245236+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: Awaiting client
2015-08-25T23:32:13.313682+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake console`
2015-08-25T23:32:13.491199+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-25T23:32:19.484033+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:32:19.502551+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-25T23:38:04.800833+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex` by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:38:13.610208+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: Awaiting client
2015-08-25T23:38:13.648793+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex`
2015-08-25T23:38:13.810042+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-25T23:38:21.272238+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-25T23:38:21.257411+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:49:01.120607+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:49:09.361381+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: Awaiting client
2015-08-25T23:49:09.436570+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-08-25T23:49:09.539804+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-25T23:49:16.952477+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-25T23:49:16.933842+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: Process exited with status 1
```

And when I run the heroku logs :

```
MacBook-Pro:theBlog MS$ heroku logs
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579573+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579609+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579629+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579667+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'  
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579686+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579738+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579757+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579776+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-08-25T22:43:43.579795+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-08-25T22:43:44.646789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T22:43:44.676708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-25T23:20:41.563452+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach WEBSOLR resource by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:20:41.563568+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:20:41.936820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-25T23:20:55.449181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 22273 -e production`
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247768+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:281:in `user_configuration_from_key'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247772+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/init.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247780+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247739+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247781+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot_rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247765+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `user_configuration'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247769+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:256:in `disabled?'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247771+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails.rb:30:in `build_session'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247784+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247787+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247785+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247790+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247791+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247793+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247797+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247808+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247775+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:02.247776+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2015-08-25T23:21:03.229459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-25T23:21:03.229459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-25T23:21:03.216723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:21:09.602918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 13571 -e production`
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306158+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `user_configuration'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306178+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306194+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306137+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306176+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot_rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306193+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306164+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:281:in `user_configuration_from_key'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306195+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306166+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:256:in `disabled?'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306197+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306168+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails.rb:30:in `build_session'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306182+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306198+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306169+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/init.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306172+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306173+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306190+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306175+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:14.306191+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
2015-08-25T23:21:15.207054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:21:16.134189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=moussa-simple-rails-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=dc366c4d-46ea-4ff9-aca3-23300655b667 fwd="158.222.193.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-25T23:21:16.358726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=moussa-simple-rails-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=de0db63a-645b-4c26-a3af-58f41b6aa66b fwd="158.222.193.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-25T23:21:15.227907+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-25T23:21:46.699099+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:21:52.671551+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: Awaiting client
2015-08-25T23:21:52.699360+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-08-25T23:21:52.915042+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-25T23:21:57.420588+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-25T23:21:57.408745+00:00 heroku[run.1067]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:32:04.600004+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake console` by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:32:13.245236+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: Awaiting client
2015-08-25T23:32:13.313682+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake console`
2015-08-25T23:32:13.491199+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-25T23:32:19.484033+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:32:19.502551+00:00 heroku[run.3036]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-25T23:38:04.800833+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex` by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:38:13.610208+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: Awaiting client
2015-08-25T23:38:13.648793+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex`
2015-08-25T23:38:13.810042+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-25T23:38:21.272238+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-25T23:38:21.257411+00:00 heroku[run.5555]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:49:01.120607+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by sarrmoussa20@yahoo.com
2015-08-25T23:49:09.361381+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: Awaiting client
2015-08-25T23:49:09.436570+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-08-25T23:49:09.539804+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-25T23:49:16.952477+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-25T23:49:16.933842+00:00 heroku[run.8600]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-25T23:51:21.238038+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=moussa-simple-rails-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=e607f590-52c7-4e13-b298-f4350d56f082 fwd="158.222.193.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-25T23:51:21.350067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=moussa-simple-rails-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=cd905e22-05e9-408d-b5c3-b672af03f93a fwd="158.222.193.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use the bundled Solr instance provided by the Sunspot gem. That's not really going to work in the Heroku environment for a couple reasons:

1. Dynos don't get the ability to communicate on arbitrary ports with other processes. Only your `web` dyno is routable on HTTP through Heroku's routers. Attempting to bind to any port other than the `$PORT` env var given to your web dyno will fail.
2. Even if you did have a clever way to run Solr either embedded in your app or as its own dyno, Heroku's filesystems are ephemeral, and you won't be able to persist your index data for any meaningful amount of time.

This is partly why Heroku created its [Addons marketplace](https://addons.heroku.com/) for specialized services that that can be integrated with apps running on Heroku.

For specialized services such as search, you'll want to use one of the addon services. For Solr, there is the [Websolr](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/websolr) addon. (Disclosure: I'm one of its founders.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the command is wrong. You are combining 2 different commands
Heroku run console
And heroku rake rakecommand
Now you want solr in heroku. For that you need to configure solr in th heroku.. 
Heroku plugin is available for solr.
And u need to start and reindex solr in heroku
By following commands

```
Rake sunspot:solr:star
Rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```